# PHP/MySQL convert 'while' statements to 'foreach'

Tags: php, mysql

Following on from a previous question, [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042502/php-mysql-2-while-statements-from-1-mysql-query), I was wondering how I would go about changing the code below into 'foreach' statements? Any help greatly appreciated, S.

```
<div id="banner-wrap">          
    <div id="banner" class="gallery">               
        <ul class="galleryBar">               

                <?php       
                $homeB=mysql_query("select * from istable where fpGallery = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 5");
                while($homeG=mysql_fetch_array($homeB)) {   
                $linkcode = $homeG['title'];
                $linkcode = str_replace(" ","",$linkcode);
                echo '
                <li>
                <a href="'.$wwwUrl.'images/'.$homeG['image'].'" rel="'.$linkcode.'">
                <img src="'.$wwwUrl.'images/tn/'.$homeG['image'].'" width="75" height="55" alt="'.$homeG['title'].'" />
                </a>
                </li>                       
                ';
                }                                   

        echo '</ul>';
         echo '</div>'; 

                while($homeGal=mysql_fetch_array($homeB)) {                             
                echo '
                <div id="'.$linkcode.'" class="overlay">
                    <h3>'.$homeGal['title'].'</h3>
                    <h4>'.$homeGal['location'].'</h4>                           
                </div>                                              
                ';
                }

                ?>          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$data = array();
while($homeG=mysql_fetch_array($homeB)) {   
    $data[] = $homeG;
}

foreach($data as $row) {
    // your code hre
}
```

But my advice to you is split your programming logic and view logic/code. You'd better try to create something as Model View Controller [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–View–Controller ]

or use a PHP Framework ([CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com))

Comment: Brilliant - adapted my code with your example and it works perfectly! Many thanks to you and all other members.

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace your `while` for a `foreach` in this situation. [mysql_fetch_array](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) / [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) only returns one row and not the whole result set from the resource passed (if the internal pointer of the connection resource is at the end, `false` is returned).

In your case if you need the whole result set and then work with it in a `foreach` you can always fetch the whole result set in an `array` (with a `while`) and then work with the `array` with a `foreach` (see infinity answer for an example). This will take much more memory/slow down the process if you have a huge result set.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to encapsulate the database access with a custom class that implements the [Iterator](http://es2.php.net/iterator) interface or drop the mysql_*() functions in favour of another library that provides classes that already implement such interface, such as PDO.

I believe that this kind of change, although interesting in the long term, makes little sense in your current situation. You should first become proficient in the use of [arrays](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the `while` loop, as the `mysql_fetch` functions only return one row at a time.

If you really wanted a `foreach()` loop, you could use a `while` loop and `mysql_fetch` to populate the data into an array, and then do a `foreach` loop after that on that array. That would give you a `foreach`, but it wouldn't get rid of the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

While loop **foreach()**

DB CREATE

> 1. id
> 2. title
> 3. href
> 4. img

```
<?php 
   $this = array();

   $db = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `'.DB_PREFIX.'product` where id order by id asc', ConnectDb()); // ConnectDb() to PHP Deprecated: mysql_query() error fix

   while($see=mysql_fetch_array($db)) {   
         $this[] = $see;
   }
?>

<ul class="product">
  <?php foreach ($this as $product) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>"><?php echo $product['title']; ?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```